# Finding Mean of a text file seperated by spaces in R Language

Tags: r

I have some files with names Reg.stt in 30 different directories containing numerical data of integer and float type. I want to average out the data in another file. I don't know codding in R language. But according to my findings this is an easy job to write such scripts in R language. The structure of file is as under... number of columns and rows can vary.

OS: Ubuntu

Folder Structure: /Desktop/folder1/Reg.stt, /Desktop/folder2/Reg.stt  ...  /Desktop/folder30/Reg.stt

```
0 0.3857 0.7942 0.0000 12.418 3.626 4 2 12 4 0.3857 0.7942 0.0000 12.418 3.626 4 2 12 4 505 
1 0 0.4269 0.8726 0.0000 11.146 3.730 19 5 8 3 0.4063 0.8726 0.0000 11.782 3.678 19 5 12 4 584 
2 0 0.4427 0.8442 0.0000 11.388 4.014 19 5 15 6 0.4184 0.8726 0.0000 11.651 3.790 19 5 12 4 561 
3 0 0.4472 0.8718 0.0000 11.928 4.134 16 5 23 6 0.4256 0.8726 0.0000 11.720 3.876 19 5 12 4 579 
4 0 0.4511 0.8893 0.0028 11.514 4.176 16 4 31 10 0.4307 0.8893 0.0000 11.679 3.936 16 4 12 4 583 
5 0 0.4546 0.8193 0.0000 11.362 4.204 6 2 6 3 0.4347 0.8893 0.0000 11.626 3.981 16 4 12 4 566
```

Comment: There is no question and no reproducible example and it your statement has nothing to do with python.

Comment: Basically you want to read every file, calculate means over columns and then mean over all data.frames?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik yes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it. I have made comments inside the code.

```
# Create a sub-folder into which we create files.
dir.create("temp_dir")
setwd("temp_dir")

# Create some files in temp_dir.
sapply(1:10, FUN = function(i) {
  xy <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10))
  write.table(xy, file = sprintf("filename_%s.txt", i), row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
})

# Find relevant files, you can use pattern to match if folder doesn't contain only
# files in question.
all.files <- list.files(pattern = "filename_")

# Read in all files. do not simplify the result because we'll need it "raw". The 
# result is a list.
all.dfs <- sapply(all.files, FUN = read.table, header = TRUE, simplify = FALSE)

# Calculate grand mean of the data.frame.
all.means <- lapply(all.dfs, FUN = function(x) mean(sapply(x, mean)))

# Corce from a list to a vector.
one.mean <- as.numeric(all.means)

# Calculate mean for each column.
mean(one.mean)

# Clean up this example.
setwd("../")
unlink("temp_dir")
```

Comment: What about, if all the text files have same names and stored in different directories. i.e. directory1/abc.txt  ...  directory2/abc.txt etc.

Comment: @AsifKhawaja See `?list.files`, specifically argument `recursive = TRUE`. This will "climb" all subdirectories and fetch files from them. You could also use `full.names` if you want absolute path names.